# perf on running process in Linux

Tags: linux, perf

For profiling, we can use perf in Linux. But all examples showing only executables.

In CentOS, is it possible to run perf tool on running process or daemon?

Answer (score 14):

`perf record` and `perf stat` support the `-p` option which you can use to specify the PID of the process to attach to. For example , the command:

```
perf stat -p 3129
```

tells `perf stat` to attach to the currently running process with PID 3129.